# ng-file-upload stuck at progress

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, ng-file-upload

Good night!.. I am a newbie working on MEAN Stack, and I'm trying to upload a picture using the ng-file-upload. This is the angular code:

```
app.controller('profilePicCtrl', ['Upload', '$scope', '$http', 
                      function(Upload,  $scope, $http){

    $scope.watch(function(){
        return $scope.file
    }, function(){
        $scope.upload($scope.file);
    });

    $scope.userID = localStorage.getItem('userID');
    $scope.upload = function(file){
        console.log("entro en upload");
        if(file){
            Upload.upload({
                url:'api/profile/edit',
                method:'POST',
                data: {userId: $scope.userID},
                file: file
            }).progress(function(evt, status){
                console.log("dale puej mijo ");
                console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            }).success(function(data, status){
                console.log('archivo subido');
            }).error(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here is the express code:

```
   module.exports.updatePhoto = function(req, res){
    var file = req.file;
    var userId = req.body.userId;
    console.log("User "+userId+ " is submitting ", file.name);
   }
```

And the last is the server-side code, where I call the controller:

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();
var profileController = require('./routes/profile-controller');
...
app.post('api/profile/edit', multipartMiddleware, profileController.updatePhoto);
```

It doesn't go thru the controller, the server never responds. Thanks in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

I had a code that wasn't letting me go into any other method different than 'GET'. This one below was the guilty one:

```
  if(req.method === "GET" || req.method === "POST"){
    if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.redirect('/#login');
    }else{
        return next();
    }
 }
```

Instead of the `or` sentence I had in the `if` just the `req.method==='GET` sentence, which was causing my code to go into an infinity loop returning the `next()` method but not finding one. Now with the `or` sentence my code goes to the `POST` methods.